# What is this extra divider line on my Dock?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, dock, group

Mysteriously, this extra divider-line has appeared between any app I launch now and the previously launched apps?

What is the purpose of this 2nd divider line? Why is it appearing now? How can I get rid of it?

See this screenshot, with pink arrow pointing to the mystery divider-line.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Recent apps

This is **recently-opened applications**, which is on by default in [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS_Mojave). To disable, open **System Preferences** > **Dock**, and uncheck **Show recent applications in Dock**.

[image: screenshot of System Preferences > Dock > Show recent applications in Dock (checkbox)]