# How do I get apps unstuck from the Dock?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, icon

I'm learning my new MacBook Pro (2023) macOS Ventura. After closing an app, I noticed the icon stays "stuck" in the Dock. I've repeatedly clicked `^(icon) > Options > Remove from Dock`. Unless I remove it manually, the icon remains in the Dock. What am I missing?

UPDATE: It's been pointed out that my question was answered at: [What is this extra divider line on my Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349502/what-is-this-extra-divider-line-on-my-dock). Apparently, my Dock was set to display recent apps—with an option to turn this off at `Settings > Desktop and Dock`.

Comment: The Dock has more than one section for apps. When you say "it remains in the dock", do you mean in the left-most "fixed apps" section where the designated app icons always remain unless they are explicitly removed as you have described or "the recently opened apps" section which would be to the right of the "fixed apps" section? These two sections would be separated by a thin vertical line.

Comment: My dock is stationed on the left (vertically)—but yes, in the "recently opened apps" section, bottom (for me). I just discovered there is a Dock option for recents, lol. I figured out how to turn it off. Thank you!